# MAX Value for a set of 60 cells in a column reoccurring

Tags: excel-2010

I am trying to figure out how to retrieve the max value in a cell block of 60 cells (1-60) in a column, put that value in the column next to it and move on to 61 for 60 cells and so on.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have values in column **A**.  In **B1** enter *1* and in **C1** enter *60*.
In **B2** enter:

```
=B1+60
```

and copy downward and in **C2** enter:

```
=C1+60
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Note:

Cols **B** and **C** are the boundarys of the sets.

Then in **D1** enter:

```
=MAX(INDIRECT("A" & B1 & ":A" & C1))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]